# C++ app hangs on exit when I envoke a script and leave the script running

Tags: c++, linux, bash, qt, shell

I have a C++/Qt program running on Ubuntu 10.04.  I am running a remote application using x-windows (ssh -X) with RSA key to prevent the password dialog.  The C++/Qt program allows the user to invoke a shell script.  The C++/Qt program must run as 'gksudo -k'.

The problem that I am having is that when I invoke the shell script from my program it causes a thread in the local C++/Qt program to hang on exit if I leave the remote application running. (I want to be able to leave the ssh session running, and not effect restarting the C++/Qt program)

From the C++ code:

```
try
{
    system(script.c_str());
}
catch (exception& e)
{
    throw;
}
catch ( ... )
{
    ThrowException("Controller::LaunchScript()");
}
```

The shell script is in /usr/local/bin, and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip_address='192.168.0.1'
remote_usr='xxusrxx'
remote_cmd='/usr/local/bin/remote_application'

cmd="ssh -X "$remote_usr"@"$ip_address" \""$remote_cmd"\""
eval $cmd &
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Update 1:

When I look at the processes running using 'ps -ef', the C++/Qt program nor the launcher script show up, but the 'ssh -X' does.  When I restart my C++/Qt program it throws an error "address already in use" like when I have tried to start the application in the past while having another instance already running.

Update 2:

I could be getting further down the rabbit hole, but I am now looking at the sudo+xauth issues and solutions.  Current failed attempt is adding:

```
export XAUTHORITY=/home/xxusrxx/.Xauthority
sudo -E -u xxusrxx
```

Also, it appears the the C++/Qt process that is hanging is defunct.  One possibility is to track the have the application "clean-up" defunct processes on startup.

Comment: running `$cmd` in the background makes sense, but it is probably causing your issue. Try this as a quick test, modify ssh args to `ssh -t -t -X ...`.  That works for this issue in shell scripts (without a C++ wrapper program). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter - I tried removing the '&' and adding the '-t -t' and I get no change in behavior.

Comment: **if** my idea will work, then the `&` should be OK. It seems less likely that it is going to work, but just to be sure, put it back in and retest. Sorry, `ssh` is a headache for everyone. I won't have much else to offer on this one. Good luck.

Comment: The problem is likely related to some daemon/service that gets started up automatically by the Qt framework, but doesn't exit automatically when your application does, and holds an X channel open.

Comment: @twalberg - How do I fix it or atleast narrow down which daemon might be holding it open?

Comment: @shellter - I appreciate the suggestion, and yes ssh is a headache.

Comment: @Axe No guarantees, but I would open another ssh session so you can 1) find the PID of the existing `sshd` for the "broken" session, 2) use `lsof` to find what network sockets that PID has open, and then use `netstat -nap` to find the PID of the process using that socket.

Comment: @twalberg - That's just it, I **WANT** the ssh session to continue after I close the C++/Qt application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try redirecting all file descriptors(stdin, stdout, stderr) to /dev/null.

In your shell script, change to this:

```
eval $cmd >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Actually I do not know why would you need eval, just call ssh directly:

```
ssh -X "$remote_usr"@"$ip_address" "$remote_cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**>/dev/null** - This, obviously, redirects the stdout.
**2>&1** - This redirects standard error(fd 2) to standard output(fd 1) which we previously redirected to /dev/null, so now they are both redirected to /dev/null
**&** - forking to background will automatically redirect stdin to /dev/null

Equivalently, directly in C++/Qt, you can just add another string with that at the end of the QStringList as Kuba Ober showed you

```
<< remote_cmd << ">/dev/null 2>&1")
```

**RESPONSE TO YOUR UPDATE:**

You say in your update that *"When I look at the processes running using 'ps -ef', the **C++/Qt program nor the launcher script show up**, but the 'ssh -X' does. "*

Does that mean that you no longer have a stuck thread/process?

Further you say *"When I restart my C++/Qt program it throws an error "address already in use""*
I suppose that is so because when you launch ssh again when the previous ssh client is still running(and forwarding X11), it connects again on the remote and there it tells the sshd server to open a port to listen for X server connections, and then it complains that that port(or interface_address:port combination) is already in use.
The simple solution, if you don't need multiple ssh connections is to kill the existing ssh connection before launching your app. Otherwise you must investigate how to force sshd to bind on another port or something like that. Maybe logging in as a different user resolves the issue automatically.

**But a big note here:** I really don't have much experience with X11 forwarding so I'm writing this greatly by just assuming how it works. I might be wrong.

Comment: I got an error when I ran that: "$1: ambigious redirect.  I got it to run by replacing $1 with /dev/null, but same result as my script.  It runs, but when I restart my C++/Qt program, it won't start.

Comment: Uhh... My bad.. it's not the dollar sign($), it's ampersand(&), I must be getting tired I guess... $1 would actually be representing the first argument forwarded to your script when it gets called... I'll fix my answer now. Try with that, however 2>/dev/null should work also... So maybe this is not the cause of your problem after all :-/

Comment: Now I've spotted the update in your question so I've updated my answer as well :)

Comment: I was able to take your suggestion, and added the 'sudo -E -u xxuserxx' to the beginning of the ssh command, but I also found that there was a defunct process that was still hanging around.  I now start the C++/Qt program with a bash script that on termination finds the PID of the C++/Qt program and kills any defunct processes related to it on exit.

Comment: Is that the same defunct process that you had at the beginning? Or do you now have a slightly different behaviour? I feel I did not help you much with my answer, yet still you have accepted it. This will hugely reduce visibility of your question to other users on stackoverflow that might be able to help you. Feel free to remove the accepted flag!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use Qt, there is no reason to use the `system` call, and there's no reason to use the helper script. Finally, wrapping a `system` call in a try-catch block is pointless since it doesn't trow exceptions. It's a C function that returns a result.

You can use `QProcess::startDetached` and your code will not wait for anything:

```
QString ip_address="192.168.0.1"
QString remote_usr="xxusrxx"
QString remote_cmd="/usr/local/bin/remote_application"

if (!QProcess::startDetached("ssh", QStringList()
  << "-X" << QString("%1@%2").arg(remote_usr).arg(ip_address)
  << remote_cmd)
  ThrowException("Controller::LaunchScript()");
```

You can similarly start the script, but there's really no point to the script.

Comment: That is what I had originally tried to do with, but got the same result.  I don't know if it has to do with the 'gksudo -k' that we run the C++/Qt program with or just the 'ssh -X'.  Regardless, this still seems to be locking something up on exit.

Comment: @Axe "I don't know if it has to do with the 'gksudo -k' that we run the C++/Qt program with or just the 'ssh -X'" Well, try it without `gksudo` first and see if that changes things. Only you can answer that one.